# Naive bayes with python but seperated two file as 'trainset.csv' and 'testset.csv'

Tags: python, naivebayes

I need to apply the naive Bayes algorithm with these files but I search for the algorithm and every example contains '1 CSV file and manually separated train and test set'. I already have 2 CSV file for the train and test set how can I apply a naive Bayes algorithm?

I tried to use sklearn train_test_split without(test_size) command but I could not do anything

Comment: Hello. If your data is already splitted you dont need to use train_test_split - just skip these steps. You can use your NB `model.fit` method on your train set and afterwars `model.predict` on the data from your test set.

Comment: Okay. My file contains strings and i can not modelling for ex.(ValueError: could not convert string to float: "'existing paid'") I am new at Python .What can i do?

Comment: It would help to know. How does your data look like. What is the code you are trying.

Comment: I handled. I am dealing with column of ['?'](missing values) rn